# Carry-on baggage restrictions for United Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I wil be flying with United Airlines (basic economy) to the US. The fight consists of two parts: One trans-Atlantic international flight, and one (US) domestic flight, all on the same United Airlines ticket.

Now, the carry-on baggage rules [here](https://www.united.com/cms/en-US/travel/pages/baggagecarry-on.aspx) state that "Most travelers can bring on board one full-sized carry-on bag plus one personal item free of charge. If you have purchased Basic Economy for a trans-Atlantic flight, you’ll still be allowed both carry-on items. For all other Basic Economy tickets, you will only be allowed one personal item". Does the restiction to one personal item apply in my case? Or does it not apply as one part of the flight is an trans-Atlantic one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baggage rules apply for the entire itinerary so you are allowed both the personal item and carry-on.

However, be prepared when boarding the domestic flight to *politely remind* the Agent that you came in on a Transatlantic flight.

But, also be prepared that by the time BE passengers are boarded, there may be no more overhead space and you will then have to gate check the bag along with any other BE or low priority passengers.  You should not have to pay the fee in this case because of your ticket type.  Again, you may have to remind the Agent that you are otherwise allowed the carry-on.

Comment: I’d say it’s likely that there won’t be any overhead bin space on the domestic flight by the time basic economy passengers board.